# Prolog - Recursive function always returning false value

Tags: recursion, prolog

I am used to implement a recursive function that checks if a given list L is written in a reverse-order:

```
orderIsReverse(L):-
    [X|Q]=L,
    [XP|_]=Q,
    (X<XP -> false; orderIsReverse(Q)),
    true.
```

However after compiling the code and prompting `orderIsReverse([3,2,1])` within [SWI Prolog](http://swi-prolog.org), I get `false` returned.

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: You are comparing `3 < 2`, which is false.

Comment: But then you need a base case. The `true` at the end is pointless.

Comment: @TomasBy `3 < 2` condition is false so there will be no returning for `false`.

Comment: @TomasBy What do you mean by 'base case'?

Comment: The problem is that when you get to `L` = `[]`, there is no base case.

Comment: It is basic terminology. Recursive call and base case. The latter is not a recursive call.

Comment: Try adding `orderIsReverse([]).` for example.

Comment: And generally, testing for the opposite and then calling `false` is not good. Test for the real condition, and then handle the failure in the logic. You don't need the procedures `true` and `false` very often.

Comment: @TomasBy Understood. `orderIsReverse([])` returns false.

Comment: Try adding it to the code.

Comment: @TomasBy Always returning false: https://gist.github.com/kaisbe/dca44bd04d8c94eef1de4d358c2213ea.

Comment: Posted it as an answer.

Comment: @TomasBy Ah, understood now. Thanks.

Comment: Your code indicates you are thinking very procedurally/imperatively with Prolog, treating it like it's programming in, say, C. This makes programming in Prolog tedious and and with poor results. You want to think relationally and think of predicate clauses as rules, not step-by-step functions. `orderIsReversed([_]).` says that a single element list is reversed. `orderIsReversed([X1,X2|T]) :- X1 > X2, orderIsReversed([X2|T]).` says that  says that *list `[X1,X2|T]` is reversed **if** `X1 > X2` is true, and list `[X2|T]` is reversed.* That completes the solution Tomas showed.

Comment: @lurker Makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the case when the input list is empty (and also when it contains one single element, as you need two for a comparison).

```
orderIsReverse([X1,X2|L]):-
  X1 > X2, orderIsReverse([X2|L]).
orderIsReverse([_]).
orderIsReverse([]).
```

Update: fixed the logic.